# Where do I put HTML project files in Android Webview Project in Eclipse?

Tags: android, html, eclipse, webview

I have created a plane android project in Eclipse amd added Webview. I have HTML project (one HTML file and one CSS file). My question is: Where (in which folder) should I put my HTML project files in Android project to make Webview show them?

Comment: ... in the **assets** folder or a subfolder in it

Answer (score 0):

Place the file in the "assets" folder

For example to use style.css in the assets folder for the webview

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();    

builder.append("<html><head><link href=\"style.css\" type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\"/></head><body>"); 

myWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/",builder.toString(),"text/html", "UTF-8", null); // load webview with html content and css present in "android_asset" which refers to the assets folder
```

Comment: Thank you! :) Can you tell me where do I put this code (in which file and between which lines)?